# How to convert the following foreach loop to linq code format?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, foreach

Code:

```
foreach (var testView in projectDataCandidate.ViewMaps
                                             .Where(vm => !vm.IsNotTestLane)
                                             .Select(this.GenerateTestView))
{
      this.SwimLaneViews.Add(testView);
      testView.ItemsOrphaned += OnItemsOrphaned;
}
```

How to write the above foreach loop in linq code format ? Thanks.

Comment: I'd consider not doing a rewrite. It's clear code to read, the presence of the `foreach` loop calls out the fact that you're actually doing something "non-LINQy" - i.e. you're actually modifying the objects you're working with - something that's obscured if you use a `foreach` extension method.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I 100% agree. Rewriting it would obscure the intent. I also suggest this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx), especially the "is harder to understand, harder to debug, and introduces closure semantics, thereby potentially changing object lifetimes in subtle ways." part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projectDataCandidate.ViewMaps
    .Where(vm => !vm.IsNotTestLane)
    .Select(this.GenerateTestView)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(testView =>
    {
        this.SwimLaneViews.Add(testView);
        testView.ItemsOrphaned += OnItemsOrphaned;
    });
```

Comment: `.ForEach` is not listed in the `intellisense`

Comment: You're also assuming that this code isn't in a PCL or Windows store app, where `ForEach` isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, you're already using LINQ for your query, and LINQ is for queries rather than commands.

#### Organise your logic

I think you're trying to improve the readability of your code. To do this, I suggest you extract out the query and command into different class members:

```
private IEnumerable<ViewMap> TestViews
{
    get
    {
        return projectDataCandidate.ViewMaps
            .Where(vm => !vm.IsNotTestLane)
            .Select(this.GenerateTestView);
    }
}

private void Process(ViewMap testView)
{
    this.SwimLaneViews.Add(testView);
    testView.ItemsOrphaned += OnItemsOrphaned;
}
```

#### Simplify your loop

Then your logic becomes the following, which is easy to read:

```
private void ProcessTestViews()
{
    foreach (var testView in TestViews)
        Process(testView);
}
```

#### Make your loop declarative

If you still don't like the look of the `foreach`, you could do this, which I think is even easier to read:

```
private void ProcessTestViews()
{
    TestViews.ToList().ForEach(Process);
}
```

#### Remove redundant `ToList`

If you don't want to convert the result to a `List` since it's not really needed, you could write an extension method to provide `ForEach` for `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var element in elements)
            action(element);
    }
}
```

This allows you to simplify your method a bit further:

```
private void ProcessTestViews()
{
    TestViews.ForEach(Process);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
projectDataCandidate.ViewMaps.Where(vm => !vm.IsNotTestLane)
                                             .Select(this.GenerateTestView).ForEach(xx=>xx.Your logic)
```

Comment: I don't think this actually compiles; I don't think a `ForEach` method exists for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do this that I can see is to force execution with a ToList, then use the ForEach function.

```
var objects = projectDataCandidate.ViewMaps
    .Where(vm => !vm.IsNotTestLane)
    .Select(this.GenerateTestView)
    .ToList();

objects.ForEach(a => SwimLaneViews.Add(a));
objects.ForEach(a => a.ItemsOrphaned += OnItemsOrphaned);
```

Comment: I think iterating over the results twice is messier than doing so once with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yes agreed, mMctadir's syntax is the best. I just wanted to outline that you will need to use the toList and force execution before using the foreach.